# anchor tag repeating controller name asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I have the following **Markup:**

```
<a href="controllerName/ActionMethodName?Pid=@Model.Collection[i].Pid">Know more</a>
```

I redirect user to this page using following **javascript:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnGoTo" value="ButtonCaption" onclick="window.location.href = '../Product/Index';" />
```

The problem is when a user is redirected the redirection is happening as:

> controllerName/controllerName/ActionMethodName...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the routes:

```
onclick="window.location.href = '@(Url.Action("Index","Product")'"
```

Don't hardcode URLs in MVC, Always use the URL helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any javascript for this. you will automatically redirected to the specified URL with that `href`. If you are using `RAZOR View Engine` then , your call should be like :

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "some text", 
    "MyAction", 
    "MyController", 
    new { myParams = "Hello" }, 
    null
)
```

which will generate the proper anchor tag:

```
 <a href="/MyController/MyAction?myParams=Hello">some text</a>
```

You can use any one of them.In your case , you can skip using Javascript by just putting `/` before your controller name.